# Webpage search in Firefox counts but "doesn't display" all search results

Tags: firefox, search

There is a search option in Firefox you can use to search for a text string on a website:

[image]

I noticed on sometimes it shows an x amount of results but when you go through the different results it "jumps" to different places but there is no result visible, and nothing is highlighted. Selecting `Highlight All` doesn't help either. I figured, there is some text in the HTML but it's not displayed on the web page and verified this theory by searching the HTML code directly. Here's an example, it will find the word `house` but nothing will be displayed:

[image]

The full title of the video is `Perfect Breaded Pork Cutles from 1767 - Classic Steak House Food...` - this is visible as an popup infobox with a mouse hover event, but not on the page itself (it's a nice channel by the way - food and history combined ;). Is there any way to make the search more user friendly? I'm thinking of an option to only search rendered/visible words or a hint which visible element is near the search result etc. Or alternatively a different approach on using the search, so I don't have to do the second part and search though the code of the web page.

This is bugging me for a long time now, any solution, hits or ideas are appreciated. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can "see" the "hidden" result through the source file:

if you "select" the result the next/previous button:

[image]

and view the source file of the page/selection (right click and select "view selection source":

[image]

Then the source part with the selected search result is shown, even it is not displayed on the rendered site.